# PHP string implode: Invalid arguments passed in

Tags: php, string, implode

```
$allProfiles = '';
foreach( array_merge( $profile, $otherProfiles )  as $all ):
    $allProfiles .= $all;
endforeach;

echo "Player all profiles: $allProfiles";
```

This prints for me `Player all profiles: NameNameNameNameName`, how can I implode by comma? When I make `$allProfiles .= implode(",", $all)`; Then I got `Invalid arguments passed in` Thanks in advance

EDIT

Just changed `$allProfiles .= $all;` to `$allProfiles[] = $all;`

Then in echo used `implode` ..

Comment: You can just do `$allPrfiles[] = $all;` in the loop, then at the bottom implode: `echo "Player all profiles: ".implode(', ',$allProfiles);` Set the `$allPrfiles` as an array at the top, not empty.

Comment: @Rasclatt yes.. noticed now, thank you ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make array like this

```
 $allProfiles = array();
 foreach( array_merge( $profile, $otherProfiles )  as $all ):
       $allProfiles[]= $all;
 endforeach;

echo "Player all profiles: ".implode(",",$allProfiles);
```